# Error when calling for last value in sequence in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to get the last value of a sequence in my database, and acording to what i found, the query should be done like this: `SELECT last_value FROM my_sequence`. However, when i hit enter, the only thing I get in the console is:

```
ERROR:  relation "my_sequence" does not exist
LINE 1: select last_value from my_sequence;
                               ^
```

Any help?

---

Edit: the sequence does exist, for I do get the name of it when I list all sequences

Comment: The error message is clear: Table/View/Alias/Whatever with name my_sequence does not exist. Maybe a typo?

Comment: @S-Man unfortunately no, I've even tried copy-pasting the name of the sequence

Comment: Wrong schema? Try my_schema.my_sequence.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much. However, i was under the impresion that i was already in that schema in my console, so i don't get why that happened

Comment: @S-Man post it as an answer so i can vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the schema you are using:

```
SELECT last_value FROM my_schema.my_sequence
```

Comment: I haven't enough reputation so as to vote, but believe me, I really do apreciate it

Comment: There you go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select currval('my_sequence')
```

OR

```
select currval('my_schema.my_sequence')
```

Comment: Same error, with and without the apostrophes

Comment: Did you tied `currval` ?

Comment: Now it does recognize the sequence, still, aonly works if i've used the sequence in the current session. Anyways, thank you so much!